# QT How to convert QByteArray number to int;

Tags: qt, type-conversion, qbytearray

Using Qt, want to convert a number(digit) in QByteArray to int.
Here is the code:

```
QByteArray ba;
ba = serial->readAll();   //ba[0] = 6;

int sum = ba[0] + 10;     //want it to do this i.e 10 + 6
qDebug()<<sum;            //output becomes nothing, I expected it to be 16;
```

How do I convert the extracted value to int so I can use it in arithmetic, as shown above.

Comment: You've got a typo - num/sum. Also what does "qDebug() << ba[0]" print?

Comment: Thanks, corrected. whats the reason for a downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [`toInt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#toInt) method

So you can convert it like this:

```
bool ok;                    // indicates success or failure
int sum = ba.toInt(&ok);
```

Alternatively you can first convert you `QByteArray` to string (for example, obtaining `char *` by calling [`data`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#data) member function and then do whatever you want with that string.

Comment: @tmoeti Please accept as answer if this solved your problem